# Is `count(*)` ever guaranteed to return the same result in a transaction at any transaction level?

Tags: postgresql, locking, transaction, concurrency, mvcc

If I create a table.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT CASE WHEN random() > 0.5 THEN x END AS x
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS x;
```

And, then I run the following in a transaction

```
BEGIN;
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM foo
  WHERE x IS NOT NULL;

  --time

  SELECT count(*)
  FROM foo
  WHERE x IS NOT NULL;
END;
```

Under what transaction level is my result guaranteed to remain the same in the transaction?

Answer (score 5):

My ten cents, and based on the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html):

Assumption: your own transaction does *not* change any relevant value from table *foo*.

Having the same `count(*)` in both your queries means:

1. You cannot have `dirty reads`, because another transaction might have written more rows into your *foo* table between the first and the second select; and you should not see them.
2. You are not really reading any column, so `nonrepeatable reads` are not an issue.
3. You cannot have `phantom reads`, that is, if another transaction changes any row whose `x` column is `NULL` to a non-null value, your transaction does not have to notice those changes affecting the `WHERE` condition.
4. I don't really know how to judge `serialization anomalies`. My educated guess is that this *isn't required*. But this is really **very open for debate**.

Under these conditions, the table from [Transaction Isolation Levels](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html#MVCC-ISOLEVEL-TABLE) makes it clear that `Repeatable read` complies with the criteria of:

1. Not having dirty reads
2. Not having non-repeatable reads
3. Not having phantom reads (in PostgreSQL, but not demanded by the standard)

... as such, it would give you the same `count(*)` in both select statements.

Comment: *"You are not really reading any column"*. But they are: `WHERE x IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Yes, you're right, but this goes into the `phantom reads` part. The terminology WRT to "phantom reads" and "non-repeatable reads" is not clear (to me, at least) from SQL standard, which means your interpretation is possibly good as well.

Comment: You are right. Serialization anomalies may happen when you insert data derived from the previous aggregate values simultaneously in two concurrent transactions. There is an example in postgres docs where both transactions aggregate data from a table and then insert the results in a way that always the other transaction's select is affected by the new insert. Therefore if both selects happen in parallel and then both inserts happen in parallel, the inserts use the same aggregate result, not the serialized ones.

Answer (score 1):

> guaranteed to remain the same "in the transaction"

That has two meanings, and that's the problem. You have what's happening outside of the transaction and what's happening inside with the "snapshot". Two things can happen to the result of `count(*)`:

- **The count can change**
  Transaction level `READ COMMITTED` (and `READ UNCOMMITTED`<sup>†</sup>).
- **The count cannot change**
  Transaction levels `REPEATABLE READ` and `SERIALIZABLE`.

Changing and not changing isn't everything you need to know. `REPEATABLE READ` and `SERIALIZABLE` work on *snapshots*.  That is to say, the `counts(*)` won't change, but that doesn't mean anything with regard to what may already changed in the database.

Let's simplify and review some things and call the initialization code above `REINIT`. We will play with only these two statements.

1. `SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE x IS NULL;`
2. `UPDATE foo SET x = 1 WHERE x IS NULL;`

Now, let's say we run two sessions

```
REINIT
1#     BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
1#     SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE x IS NULL;
   2#  UPDATE foo SET x = 1 WHERE x IS NULL;
1#     SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE x IS NULL;
```

Now what does `count(*)` show in `1#`'s transaction? And after both transactions commit, `#1` and then `#2`? Spoiler alert:

> In the transaction, it will show the same number. Outside of the transaction, it will show 0 because the `UPDATE` has already committed.

Now, in a lower transaction level then the `REPEATABLE READ`, like `READ COMMITTED` the second `SELECT` by `#1` see the committed rows. And, in a higher transaction level. The first `SELECT count(*)` will obtain a *predicate lock* on just the rows where `x IS NULL`. So then what happens when we move up a level to `SERIALIZABLE` and run the same sequence, now with predicate lock?

```
REINIT
1#      BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
1#      SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE x IS NULL;
   2#   UPDATE foo SET x = 1 WHERE x IS NULL;
1#      SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE x IS NULL;
```

Spoiler alert:

> Nothing. Same thing.

Why? **The concurrency model doesn't care about `UPDATE`s to things *unless* something also tries to modify those rows and both intend to commit.** Both are `SELECT`ing and **not** modifying their snapshots. So by extension,

```
if (SELECT count(*) 
      FROM foo
     WHERE x IS NULL
   ) < arg THEN
    RETURN 0 ;
end if ;
```

- Then in the default transaction level, `READ COMMITTED` it may see a number that is not the same as the rest of the transaction -- a concurrent transaction could have committed between the second `SELECT`. That makes it useless WITHOUT `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE`.
- But in the other transaction modes you could either face a lock issue in `REPEATABLE READ`, or a failure upon commit in `SERIALIZABLE` if anything else touches the table from outside of the transaction. So again, there is limited point. If the `count(*)` query return rows, and, then, for example, other code may attempt to update those rows just to find that they've already been modified or that they're no longer there when the working snapshot goes to commit.

So don't conditionally do stuff in transactions. Do stuff, and then handle it.

---

† The SQL standard provides for a level `READ UNCOMMITTED`. In PostgreSQL [that level aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33646012/642706) that to the tighter isolation level `READ COMMITTED`.