# Postgres: Explicit lock with transactions

Tags: postgresql, locking, transaction

I am a beginner in SQL world and have some doubts regarding transaction/locking:

- In postgres, do transaction also ensures locking of rows(preferable)/tables until it is completed?
- Also, if there are two transactions through different queries, will second one wait for the first one to complete i.e. will it be serial or concurrent?

I think both points infers same but I am not sure so posting both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In postgres, do transaction also ensures locking of rows(preferable)/tables until it is completed?

No, transactions don't ensure locking. Transactions ensure only that whatever is transacting is done *atomically*. That is to say, that it either *all* succeeds, or it *all* fails. How it does what it does, and what it is doing it to is totally controlled by you.

For instance, PostgreSQL currently supports [three isolation levels](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/transaction-iso.html),

- Read committed
- Repeatable read
- Serializable

These three isolation levels either see and operate can see the data directly, or a snapshot of the data at the time transaction starts.

Only in the last mode *serializable* is any attempt to be made that the transaction commits in a serialized fashion. Whether or not enough of an attempt is made is another question.

All locking in PostgreSQL can be done explicitly or implicitly (the DDL command know how to lock efficiently to get the job done). Usually, [explicit locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) are shunned. But in same cases, including under serializable, it's the only way to be sure data has *not* been added since the transaction started.

Comment: So setting isolation level as Serializable  should take care of the point 2, I have mentioned?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to answer that question, likely yes, insofar as modification to the database goes. But, I was quite shocked last week to find out that the `select(*)` on the database doesn't predicate lock the whole table. This is likely out of the realm of beginner questions, so we can just pretend the answer is a simple "yes"?

Comment: I don't think people *want* to grab Serializable right away. There are usually better things to do than write Stored Procs and abundant transactions to begin with. And, when you do have to write them you usually don't need serializable.

Comment: If you want to geek out over an edge case, then check out [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160242/2639) from a question I wrote this weekend.